# 500 Internal Server Error on one of my cloud endpoint methods when deployed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

All of my Cloud Endpoints methods work locally, and all but one work when the app is deployed. Here is the method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listUrl", path ="article/urls", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public String[] listUrl() {
    List<Article> articles = getArticleList();
    String[] urlArray = new String[articles.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Article article : articles)
        urlArray[i++] = article.getUrl(); 
    return urlArray;
}
```

I know that the three accepted return types are "a POJO, an array or a Collection." But I thought that perhaps the `String[]` was causing the error, so tried returning a collection of `String`s instead.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listUrl", path ="article/urls", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<String>/*String[]*/ listUrl() {
    List<Article> articles = getArticleList();
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String[] urlArray = new String[articles.size()];
    //int i = 0;
    for (Article article : articles)
        urls.add(article.getUrl());
        //urlArray[i++] = article.getUrl(); 
    return /*urlArray*/ CollectionResponse.<String> builder().setItems(urls).build();
}
```

But to no avail. I continue to get "500 Internal Server Error."

[image: 500: Internal Server Error]The most bizarre part is that when I look at the logs in the admin console, it states that the request went through fine:

```
2013-09-22 22:08:00.715 /_ah/spi/com.example.hiserver.ArticleEndpoint.listUrl 200 55ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0

xx.xxx.xx.xxx(my IP) - - [22/Sep/2013:22:08:00 -0700] "POST /_ah/spi/com.example.hiserver.ArticleEndpoint.listUrl HTTP/1.1" 200 129 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" "hylyt-it.appspot.com" ms=56 cpu_ms=21 cpm_usd=0.000014 app_engine_release=1.8.4 instance=00c61b117cdf561948b997f4ec6be2ca72c139d1
```

Comment: can you add some [additional logging](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) in your methods and check

Comment: I've added logging to every single line of that method, and everything works as expected within the method. I even get a 200 on the admin console logs, but the client side shows error 500.

Comment: I suspect that the reason for this is that with Cloud Endpoints, [the return value type cannot be simple type such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array or a Collection](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities) (implicitly) **of `POJO`s**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on willmas comment i fiddled around with my code and found out that you cannot use generics as return parameter. That actually makes sense when you think about how appengine should go about and serialize that stuff to json. Then again it doesn't when it works on local devserver.
Anyhow, in my case i used a List which worked fine on local dev server but not when deployed. The solution was to create a

```
public class StringResult {
    private String result;
    /* getters and setters */ 
}
```

In your case you could use

```
public class StringArrayResult {
    private String[] result;
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Thank you @willma for pointing into the right direction.

Comment: No worries. This is also what I ended up doing. Dan Holevoet from Google confirmed the inability to return collections of generics in the comments of [the answer to one of my questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20196518/1720014).