# GAE Endpoint Error 500 on Deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I just create a small endpoint backend services, and works fine on localhost. But when the application is deployed to GAE, I got a internal server error:

I edit my class to be simple as possible, but didn't make any difference.
Here is my code:

```
@Api(name = "meetApp", version = "v1")
public class RegisteredUsers {

    @ApiMethod(name = "users.list", httpMethod = "get")
    public String[] getRegisteredUsers(){
          return new String [] {"test"};
        }
```

Here is the error message, on the admin console, the request are marked as okay (200).

[image]

Comment: @DanHolevoet could you clarify the below?

Comment: possible duplicate of [500 Internal Server Error on one of my cloud endpoint methods when deployed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952299/500-internal-server-error-on-one-of-my-cloud-endpoint-methods-when-deployed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return primitives or any collection/array of primitives, and yet the SDK hasn't yet been updated to prevent you from building your app or testing locally when doing so. You'll need to create a POJO:

```
public class MyArray() {
  private String[] strings;
  public MyArray(String[] strings) {
    this.strings = strings;
  }
}
```

Then your method becomes

```
public MyArray getRegisteredUsers(){
  return new MyArray(new String[]{'test'});
}
```

Then, wherever you're receiving the object, you'll have to access the `String` as `myArray.strings[0]`.

Stupid, I know. See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188253/more-info-on-cloud-endpoints-return-types) for more details. You'll see in the comments to the answer that @DanHolevoet (who works on Cloud Endpoints and took the time to edit your question but not answer it) confirmed that you can't return collections of primitives.

I don't know why that's the case, frankly. In the answer to [this same question I asked 4 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952299/500-internal-server-error-on-one-of-my-cloud-endpoint-methods-when-deployed) @JoSo states

> That actually makes sense when you think about how appengine should go about and serialize that stuff to json.

I'm not knowledgeable on the subject, but I disagree. As I understand it, JavaScript arrays are the same as objects, just with enumerated instead of named attributes, so an array of strings should be easy to serialize and interpret. If the local devserver can do it…

I'll stop ranting. I'm sure there's a good reason for not allowing it. But would be interested in knowing what it is, because it would be damn useful.

Edit: improved the code

Comment: I was just doing a pass through retagging things. :) Your answer is correct.

Comment: @DanHolevoet Thanks, and sorry for calling you out. I was wondering more along the lines of why CE can't return arrays of primitives.